# Can I simulate a click on a hyperlink with jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have seen a couple of Stack Overflow posts which apparently relate to my question but none of them seem to do what I want.

I have a nested structure to display hierarchies (business units and brands) in a report:

```
<tr class="BrandRow1">
    <td>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr class='BrandRow1 StoreRow1'>
...
</tr>
<tr class='BrandRow1 StoreRow2'>
...
</tr>
```

and within this layout I use `A` tags to show/hide the 'child' content (by making use of the `class` attributes.

On load, I want to show all the 'nodes' if  `$('.StoreRow2').length` is less than say 4.

I use a function to do the toggling:

```
// Allow an item to toggle other items' visibility
$(".VisibilityToggle").click(function () {
    var ControlledClass = findClass($(this), "Toggles-");
    if (ControlledClass != "") {
        $("." + ControlledClass).toggle();
        var Text = $(this).attr("rel");
        if (Text != "") $(this).attr("rel", $(this).attr("rev")).attr("rev", Text).text(Text);
    }
    return false;
});
```

and what I'd like to do is trigger the 'toggling' open by calling this from JS code.

I thought something like '$(".VisibilityToggle").click()` would do what I want but this doesn't seem to work in my code, but **does** if I call it manually via the JS console in Chrome. I suspect its to do with my code running before the events have been bound to the page.

Can you please assist?

E.g. Markup

```
...
<tr class='BrandRow TRBrand_2'>
    <td class="Level0">
        <p>
            <a id="DesktopApp0_ctl00_rptReportBrand_ctl01_A_Brand" rel="-" rev="+" class="button toggleButton SummaryToggle VisibilityToggle Toggles-BrandId_2">+</a> &nbsp;<strong>Brand2</strong>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            34</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            21</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            22</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0.0&#37;</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            1
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            34.0
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class='SiteRow BrandId_2 TRStore_10'>
    <td class="Level1">
        <p>
            <a id="DesktopApp0_ctl00_rptReportBrand_ctl01_rptSites_ctl00_A_Site" rel="-" rev="+" class="button toggleButton SummaryToggle VisibilityToggle Toggles-TRSiteUser_10">+</a>&nbsp; <span class="Bold">BrandX - Store 10</span>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            14</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            9</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            8</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0.0&#37;</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0.0
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class='UserRow TRStoreUser_10'>
    <td class="Level2">
        <p>
            <img src="/img/icons/spacer.png" alt=" " />
            &nbsp;Clarke Kent
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            3</p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="Drive5Graphic">
        <span class=" d5_3">1</span><span class=" d5_3">2</span><span class=" d5_3">3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span class=" plus">+</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            &#8734;</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class='UserRow TRSiteUser_10'>
    <td class="Level2">
        <p>
            <img src="/img/icons/spacer.png" alt=" " />
            &nbsp;Alexie Sayle
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            2</p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="Drive5Graphic">
        <span class=" d5_2">1</span><span class=" d5_2">2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span class=" plus">+</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            &#8734;</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class='UserRow TRSiteUser_10'>
    <td class="Level2">
        <p>
            <img src="/img/icons/spacer.png" alt=" " />
            &nbsp;Anders Bottom
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            1</p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="Drive5Graphic">
        <span class=" d5_1">1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span class=" plus">+</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            &#8734;</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class='UserRow TRSiteUser_10'>
    <td class="Level2">
        <p>
            <img src="/img/icons/spacer.png" alt=" " />
            &nbsp;Daniella Ecclescake
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            1</p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="Drive5Graphic">
        <span class=" d5_1">1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span class=" plus">+</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            &#8734;</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class='UserRow TRSiteUser_10'>
    <td class="Level2">
        <p>
            <img src="/img/icons/spacer.png" alt=" " />
            &nbsp;Mark E Smith
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            1</p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="Drive5Graphic">
        <span class=" d5_1">1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span class=" plus">+</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            &#8734;</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class='UserRow TRSiteUser_10'>
    <td class="Level2">
        <p>
            <img src="/img/icons/spacer.png" alt=" " />
            &nbsp;Matthew Bannister
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            1</p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="Drive5Graphic">
        <span class=" d5_1">1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span class=" plus">+</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            &#8734;</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class='UserRow TRSiteUser_10'>
    <td class="Level2">
        <p>
            <img src="/img/icons/spacer.png" alt=" " />
            &nbsp;Raj Patel
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="Drive5Graphic">
        <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span class=" plus">+</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            0</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            &#8734;</p>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

Comment: Yes you can. $(linkObject).click()

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, .click() isn't working in my page. I think its something to do with calling it before the events have been bound (I've put my call to .trigger/.click in the $(document).ready(...); ) because if I call the function via the JS console in Chrome, it works exactly as you say. Baffled.

Comment: I don't know what .ABrand is, please give more markup

Comment: .A_Brand is an Anchor with a class of VisibilityToggle and an other class of Toggles-BrandRowX (where X is a brandId).

Comment: @5arx: Can you add the markup to your question?

Comment: @Town - markup added as requested.

Comment: @5arx: There's no `ABrand` class in there so your `$('.ABrand')` selector won't work.

Comment: is this content dynamically added to the page?  if so, i'd look at Town's suggestion below to use the `.live()` method.

Comment: @Town - apologies was using 'ABrand' for illustrative purposes only. Have modified the OP. FYI it is $(".VisibilityToggle).click() that I use and as I said it works perfectly via the console once the page is loaded/ready. The content is server-generated by ASP.Net (not AJAX though) so its not 'dynamically added' via Javascript. I just want the call to happen once everything is ready on the (server-generated page)

Comment: @5arx: I built you [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/RHQeg/) - are either of those what you want do?  Note the additional `.click()` to fire the handler once the event is hooked up.

Comment: @Town - many thanks for your responses. Yes, that sort of thing. My manual clicks on the anchors work exactly as per your example. But what I want to do is expand every 'node' in code on page load if there are less than a certain number of child nodes. I thought calling x.click() in $(document).ready(...) would do it.

Comment: @Town - http://jsfiddle.net/Town/RHQeg/  I've put a call to $(".ttb").click() in the $(function) and it works exactly as I'd like i.e. opens everything up on load. Why, I wonder, will it not work in my case? Something to do with ASP.Net?

Comment: @Town - Sorry, that should have been http://jsfiddle.net/5arx/RHQeg/4/

Comment: @5arx: You don't need that extra `click()` with my example, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Town/RHQeg/6/

Comment: @Town - I do if I want all the toptobottom nodes to open when the document loads?

Comment: @5arx: just add/remove the additional `click()` depending on what you want - see the comments in that example.

Comment: @Town - thanks. I see what you mean. Unfortunately, I have to make use of the VisibilityToggle function as its part of the standard clientside library here. I just want to simulate a click on the anchor(s) attached to it and thereby cause that block of code to run.

Answer (score 4):

you could use trigger:

```
$(".ABrand").trigger('click');
```

Is that what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: It is, and it does work via the JS Console, but not if I put the call inside of $(document).ready(...); Please see my revisions to the original question.

Comment: Perhaps you call the .trigger('click') before actually binding the click() event?  then the command .trigger('click') would simply not be recognized..

Comment: Try putting the triggering into setTimeout and check if things work then: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the syntax you have: [**click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) will trigger a click on the element.

```
$('.ABrand').click();
```

More markup is required to properly answer your question I would think, but take a look at [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which can be used outside `document.ready` if you're worried that things aren't getting hooked up in time.

```
$(".VisibilityToggle").live("click", function() { ... } );

$("#Container").delegate(".VisibilityToggle", click", function() { ... } );
```

Comment: The visibilitytoggling works fine via actual clicks and also if i manually call it in the JS console. So I guess its to do with the events not being bound at the point at which $(document).ready(...) runs ...? I've tried putting it in $(document).load(...) but no dice :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble timing the event bind (i.e. the `.click(function(){})`) and the event trigger (i.e. the `.click()`), why not just chain the two together?

```
$('.ABrand').click(function() {
    // do 3 flips, 5 somersaults and a pirouette
}).click();
```

This way, you're **sure** the click trigger gets called after the click bind.